# App webview browser metrics data collected automatically in app folder

Tags: android, android-webview

I notice a wired issue with my app, every time the app starts up it collect data inside files folder.

Data is collected in directory files/app_webview and it contains a file of 4MB named browsermetrics.

This data is never deleted and it is flooding the memory of the phone.

I tried to update webview app on my phone but the problem remains

Answer (score 0):

It seems a problem related to a specific version of an SDK (version 2.5.0) https://githubhot.com/repo/adform/adform-tracking-android-sdk/issues/19

The problem it seems that has been fixed in version 2.5.2